# zend plugin for eclipse

Tags: zend-framework, eclipse-plugin, zend-studio

i am planning to start develop a website that uses webservices , i am thinking using zend framework.

as i am pretty much new for zend , i don't know much about its tools and configuration

i have eclipse installed in my computer , now is there something  like zend plug in that i can download and install in eclipse.

As i have download the Eclipse PHP Development Tools (PDT) but its a separate eclipse studio only , but i want to use it from my already installed eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

There is a branded version of Eclipse called Zend Studio but it is pretty expensive.

Check out Netbeans.

Answer (score 1):

I have been using PHPeclipse and it has worked great.

This is their tutorial how to install :

http://www.phpeclipse.com/wiki/Installation

Answer (score 0):

PDT is not studio only, you can use it with any version of Eclipse. If you already have an Eclipse installation you'll want to add their update site and then install the plugin that way. See the installation instructions here: http://wiki.eclipse.org/PDT/Installation for whichever Eclipse version you have.

Zend Studio is based on PDT, and I believe it has better ZF integration but it is a commercial product.

Comment: Does PDT have any ZF integration at all?

Comment: Not as far as I know, but don't take that as a negative thing. Code completion works great, all integration can really give you is class generation via. Zend Tool which you can do via. the command line easily enough.

Comment: the cook thing about integrated zf in ide is for example easy-to-follow dependencies between view and controller (like code completion of view vars). Otherwise, I agree with you, zf tool helps a lot.